# Visualizing Graph in OrientDB by @class

Tags: graph, orientdb

I would to visualize graph in OrientDB Studio automatically with @class rather than @rid  for all vertices and edges.
The only way that I found is by clicking on each object and changing the display setting. But I would to get the same result directly.

How can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be available in the next releases, see: https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb-studio/issues/498